# Скролл в listview

Tags: android

Всем привет! Скажите пожалуйста кто знает как убрать резиновость скроллбара в Listview. Т.е когда в ListView достигаешь конца строк, то она как бы дальше идёт оставляя пустое место. Как это исправить???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
view.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Необходимо учесть, что метод доступен начиная с 9 API и выше.